# Local area network or internet connection problem

Tags: gmail, facebook, internet

I'm not able to see any pictures in my facebook account but when I'm trying to open one of my friend's account it was working fine and showing everything as usual.

Also I'm not able to get my chat list on gmail and showing message

> Unable to reach gmail. Please check your internet connection or company's network settings

while internet connection is working fine. I can guess that it might be some network setting fault but I'm newbie to face this kind of issues so can anyone please help me to figure out this issue?